# How to see simple txt files under ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I use **NLog** to generate log files under `log` folder and file name looks like `2014-01-16.txt`.

I would like to access it somehow i.e.

```
http://localhost:20168/log/2014-01-16.txt
```

Is it possible to configure somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure your routing to ignore txt files:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("log/{file}.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about subfolder log?

Comment: I mean your solution is working fine for the root folder. But files are under subfolder LOG